# Azure Policy Storage Account Diagnostic Logging

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-monitoring, azure-policy

I have been struggling to get this policy to fully check that blob, file, Queue, and Table services are properly configured with diagnostic settings. The end result would be to ensure each storage service has diagnostic logging being sent to a log analytics workspace for StorageRead, StorageWrite, and StorageDelete categories.

To note this is using the newer method described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/monitor-blob-storage?tabs=azure-portal

The main issue I have been trying to solve is the logic to detect this across all blob services. The deployment logic works fine, its just the compliance check part to ensure blob, file, Queue, and Table services are enabled. Currently the below returns

`No related resources match the effect details in the policy definition. (Error code: Not Found)`

```
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "field": "type",
      "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "[parameters('effect')]",
      "details": {
        "type": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings",
        "existenceCondition": {
            "allOf": [
                {
                "count": {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/logs[*]",
                  "where": {
                    "allOf": [
                      {
                        "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/logs[*].category",
                        "in": [
                            "StorageRead",
                            "StorageWrite",
                            "StorageDelete"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/logs[*].enabled",
                        "equals": "[parameters('logsEnabled')]"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "greater": 0
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/workspaceId",
                "equals": "[parameters('logAnalytics')]"
              }
            ]
        },
```

Comment: Could you please tell me why you check category? I think you just need to check if log has been enabled.

Comment: To ensure each category is enabled for logging. I tried just the `{
                        "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/logs[*].enabled",
                        "equals": "[parameters('logsEnabled')]"
                      } ` as well and that doesn't work either.

Comment: please try to `"existenceCondition":{"allOf":[{"anyof":[{"field":"Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/metrics.enabled","equals":"True"},{"field":"Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/logs.enabled","equals":"True"}]},{"field":"Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/workspaceId","equals":"[parameters('logAnalytics')]"}]}`